# Python POpen Stdout not returning back when running python

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess, stdout, popen

**READ UPDATE!!!**

I'm having an issue getting output from a Python POpen from the subproccess module.

It works fine on commands such as 'ls' , 'node' , and 'python3 -m pip install requests'.

However When I run a simple python file, such as 'python3 test.py' that contains:

```
print("Hello World!")
```

It does not output. Nor does it work with:

```
sys.stdout.write()
```

It runs the code, this can be proven by this code being put in test.py

```
f = open("text.txt","w")
f.write("Hello :P")
f.close()
```

And it Writing to the file just fine.

Here is the code extracted from the main file:

```
def executeCmd(cmd):
    filename = "cmdlog_{}.txt".format(cmd.replace(" ","-").replace(".","-").replace("/","-"))
    with io.open(filename, 'wb') as writer, io.open(filename, 'rb', 1) as reader:
        process = sb.Popen(cmd, stdout=writer,stderr=writer, cwd=oss.getcwd(),shell=True)
        while process.poll() is None:
            rd = reader.read()
            sys.stdout.write(rd.decode("UTF-8"))
            time.sleep(0.1)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        rd = reader.read().decode("UTF-8")
        sys.stdout.write(rd)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        oss.remove(filename)
```

As Extra Info, That function is called as a thread, from another thread that revives data from a socket. Hence the the dictionary 'data' bellow and the send function above.

```
threading.Thread(target=proccessListen,args=([data["cmd"],data["name"]]),daemon=True).start()
```

I'm at my wits end here, with this issue occurring on multiple os's and machines.
With no fix yet found, and not related article a few hours worth of googling could not find, I request your help

Thank in advance, Sam.

---

**UPDATE:**
After 1/2 hour of playing with code, and searching online to fix the new issue, I've hit a block again.

Here is my new code:

```
import io
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import time

def executeCmd(cmd):
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,cwd=os.getcwd(),shell=True)
    print("Started")
    while process.poll() is None:
      line = process.stdout.readline()
      sys.stdout.write(line)
      #process.stdout.flush()
      time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Ended")

executeCmd("python3 test.py")
```

And in test.py

```
print("Hello")
count = 0
import time
while True:
  time.sleep(2)
  count = count + 1
  print("Output: {}".format(count))
```

The Problem is that process.stdout.readline() blocks the code, meaning it can never read the output, but why. This is taken from a [forum page](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2015/01/28/getting-realtime-output-using-python) and modified. Neither Worked, Both with the same issue, I've searched and gone through many other stack overflow questions, and none of the solutions worked.I also tried something with an non-blocking flag (I'm not sure of what I was doing). It worked for others, but I got a OSERROR. Although that looks like a difficult route to take.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Sam

Comment: Can you remove all the irrelevant stuff and give us a [mcve] so we can run and debug your code?

Comment: righto - done as asked

Comment: OK, I assume you've got the obvious imports at the top, plus `import os as oss` (as well as `import os`) and `import subprocess as sb`?

Comment: If so, when I run this code, in Python 2.7, 3.6, or 3.7, on macOS and Ubuntu, it works.

Comment: yes - have sorry forgot to add them, I will add now. don't forget sys

Comment: Thats.... Weird.. Windows it does not work, Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 and nothing. Centos neither.

Comment: I suspect your problem is with buffering. You're using the default `buffering` for the pipes, and also piping the output to a default-buffered binary file, and there's nobody flushing any of that anywhere. So there's no guarantee that it'll show up at any particular time until close, not even if you wait 20 seconds instead of 0.5. You could fix this by removing all the buffering everywhere… but why are you even writing to a file to read from it? Why not just read off the pipe?

Comment: Right, Ah, forgot to add, the python file I need to run is a socket server, so the script has a While loop, I tied it without, and and it works.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that last comment. But if there's something you can add to your example code to make it reproduce the error you're looking to debug, please do that.

Comment: Right, Sorry I did not refresh, The code has a While Loop in it, so your above comment makes scene, it only does it on exit. I tried adding sys.stdout.flush() but that does not work could, you add an example on how to fix it?

Comment: `sys.stdout.flush` isn't going to help, because the relevant buffer isn't on `sys.stdout`, it's either on `writer`, or on Python's side of the pipe, or on the pipe itself. You really need to make both the `Popen` and `writer` unbuffered. Or, as I said, just stop using a file in the first place, and the problem will not exist to be solved.

Comment: Right @abarnert I've done, that I've moved from file to the pipe stdout, however, i've come back to the error, that made me move to a file in the first place, it just blocks it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my working code:

```
import sarge
import time
import sys

cmd = sarge.run("python3 test.py",async_=True,stdout=sarge.Capture(buffer_size=1))
print("Hello World")
while True:
  time.sleep(0.5)
  sys.stdout.write("." + str(cmd.stdout.read()))
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

The code can be modifed to get rid of the `b''` and the `.`

Answer (score 0):

`process.poll()` returns something other than None as soon as the subprocess finishes executing.  That says *absolutely nothing* about whether or not you've read all of the subprocess's output!  You need to keep calling `process.stdout.readline()` in a loop until it returns an empty string - in fact that's the only loop you need in this case, since `process.poll()` isn't giving you any information that you're actually using.